# How to properly modify json in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The goal is to execute some crud operations on a json I have stored in state. The json structure is not fixed, but rather changing and dynamic.

I use a recursive functional component to display the json structure. It has a function that records the json hierarchy within which the given value is stored whenever a value is selected. Looks something like this: ["arrayName", "arrayIndex", "objectName", "key", "value"]. At this point I know where this value resides in the json structure, although I'm not sure how to continue from here. In the end, I don't find this useful.

The functional component has this signature

```
const DisplayValue = ({ structure, category, value, onEdit })
```

The function looks like this

```
const handleEdit = (structure, val) => {
    structure.unshift(val)
    onEdit(structure, category)
  }
```

And is called depending on some conditions, for example

```
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid grey', padding: 10 }}>
        {value.map((element, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <DisplayValue
                structure={structure}
                value={element}
                onEdit={() => handleEdit(structure, i)}
              />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Finally if the value is neither an array or object:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Button variant='light' onClick={() => handleEdit(structure, value)}>
        {value}
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
```

Is there someone with experience with handling and modifying json structures, willing to point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is NO JSON here. You are discussing the modification of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out man

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get a component to directly change the value of one of its props, which is not recommended.

If your changes only affect downstream/child components then you could store the mutated state in component state instead of component props.  If you do this, you'll want to use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) since you're using a functional component.

If you really do want the props to change, since the changes might affect something higher up in the component hierarchy where the props are provided or in-between, you'll want to either use a callback to affect the value higher up in the component hierarchy or look into using a state management API such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which is my recommendation for such state modifications in general.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll see what I can do with states instead, I think that is the way to go. But I'm not entirely sure about the logic of the CRUD operations of the object(s). How would you use the values of the states of the DisplayValue components to update, delete a value in the objects (in main/App component which is what is being displayed) ?

Comment: One way to do this is to have the component that is the 'source' of the property value provide a mutation function that it passes to child components; when the child wants to modify the property it's really telling the component that owns that data that it should change it, after which the changes will propagate back down to the child component.